# How would I make this script stop sending the mouse's hit coordinates to the server after the player hits a specific key?

Tags: lua, user-input, roblox

So, I currently have a button on the players screen, that when they click it, it will check to see if the player clicks anywhere in the world, and send their mouse's hit coordinates to the server. The server will then use those to make a specific part (it will soon work with models) go to wherever the mouse is when the player hits the left mouse button. That is working just fine. However, I want to make it to where if the player hits the letter 'E' before or after they have set the part's position, it will basically stop sending the mouse hit data to the server, and move on.

I am still learning how to use UserInputService. *UserInputService.InputBegan* and *UserInputService.InputEnded*, aren't working like I hoped they would. Can someone help me out with this?

Here is the code:

Local Script:

```
userInputService.InputBegan:Connect(function(input)     
        if input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.MouseButton1 then
            movePartEvent:FireServer(math.ceil(mouse.Hit.X), math.ceil(mouse.Hit.Y), math.ceil(mouse.Hit.Z))
        end

        if input.UserInputType == Enum.KeyCode.E then
            print("Part placed...")
        --Exit the userInput part of the code here --
        end
    end)
```

Server Script:

```
local replicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local movePartEvent = replicatedStorage:WaitForChild("MovePartEvent")

movePartEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(...)   
    local tuppleArgs = {...}
    local player  = tuppleArgs[1]
    local value1  = tuppleArgs[2]
    local value2  = tuppleArgs[3]
    local value3  = tuppleArgs[4]

    local function movePartOnEvent(part)        
        part.Position = Vector3.new(value1, value2, value3)
    end

    movePartOnEvent(game.Workspace.MovingPart)
end)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So I decided to use the Mouse.KeyDown function instead. I just learned that you can still use that. However, I wouldn't mind still getting an answer for the code above, because it may come in handy in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a variable that decides whether the client is still sending the data to the server. When you press "E" it will change the value of the variable.

```
local movingPart = true;

userInputService.InputBegan:Connect(function(input)     
        if input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.MouseButton1 and movingPart then
            movePartEvent:FireServer(math.ceil(mouse.Hit.X), math.ceil(mouse.Hit.Y), math.ceil(mouse.Hit.Z))
        end

        if input.UserInputType == Enum.KeyCode.E then
            print("Part placed...")
            movingPart = false;

        --Exit the userInput part of the code here --
        end
    end)
```

Now it stops sending the mouse position to the server when you have pressed "E". If you want to move another part you would have to set the variable "movingPart" to true again.